# Como obtener fecha almacenada en MYSQL y mostrarla en un JDATECHOOSER desde java

Tags: java, mysql

mi pregunta es **como puedo mostrar una fecha ya almacenada en mi BD en un JDATECHOOSER?** Tengo un JFRAME en el cual tiene una serie de campos y tengo un JDATECHOOSER en el cual necesito cargar la fecha almacenada previamente.
El metodo que utilizo para cargar los datos es el siguiente:

```
private void cargarDatos() {
        obtener(idModificado);
        producto.setProducto(jtxtProducto.getText());
        producto.setCantidad(Double.valueOf(jtxtCantidad.getText()));
        producto.setPrecioCosto(Double.valueOf(jtxtPrecioCosto.getText()));
        producto.setPrecioVenta(Double.valueOf(jtxtPrecioVenta.getText()));
        producto.setMarca(jtxtMarca.getText());
        producto.setDescripcion(jtxtDescripcion.getText());
        Categoria cboCat = (Categoria)jcboCategoria.getSelectedItem();
        int idCat = cboCat.getIdcategoria();
        producto.setIdcategoria(idCat);
        Proveedor cbo = (Proveedor) jcboProveedores.getSelectedItem();
        int id = cbo.getIdproveedor();
        producto.setIdproveedor(id);
        int año = jdcFechaVencimiento.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mes = jdcFechaVencimiento.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dia = jdcFechaVencimiento.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        String fecha = año+"/"+mes+"/"+dia;
        producto.setFechaVencimiento(fecha);
        producto.setImage(fileImagen);
        producto.guardar();
    }
```

Mi metodo **obtener**

```
public void obtener(int idProd) {
        List arrayCboCategoria = new ArrayList();
        List arrayCboProveedor = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
            CallableStatement obtenerCliente = miComando.prepareCall("call obtener_producto(?)");
            obtenerCliente.setInt(1, idProd);
            obtenerCliente.execute();
            ResultSet rs = obtenerCliente.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                jtxtIdProducto.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("idproducto")));
                jtxtProducto.setText(rs.getString("producto"));
                jtxtCantidad.setText(rs.getString("cantidad"));
                jtxtPrecioCosto.setText(rs.getString("precio_costo"));
                jtxtPrecioVenta.setText(rs.getString("precio_venta"));
                jtxtMarca.setText(rs.getString("marca"));
                jtxtDescripcion.setText(rs.getString("descripcion"));
                arrayCboCategoria.add(new Categoria(rs.getInt("idcategoria"), rs.getString("categoria")));
                arrayCboProveedor.add(new Proveedor(rs.getInt("idproveedor"), rs.getString("nombre")));
                jdcFechaVencimiento.setDateFormatString("fechaVencimiento");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar obtener el producto:\n"
                    + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        if (arrayCboCategoria.size() > 0) {
            if (arrayCboProveedor.size() > 0) {
                jcboCategoria.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(arrayCboCategoria.toArray()));
                jcboProveedores.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(arrayCboProveedor.toArray()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Al querer modificar un producto me sale **java.lang.NullPointerException** en la linea `int año = jdcFechaVencimiento.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR);`. Mi atributo de la clase **producto** es de tipo `String` **fechaVencemiento**, por eso transformo la fecha a `string` cuando la almaceno, pero yo ahora necesito mostrarla, leerla lo que ya almacene.
Agradecería mucho su ayuda. Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Tienes muchas preguntas del tipo "Problema al sacar de base de datos y poner en el GUI". Por favor, estudia tus programas y acota tus preguntas. Cuando trabajas con BD da igual si los datos vienen o van del GUI o de cualquier otra parte, de la misma manera al mostrar unos datos da igual si vienen de BD o no. Si haces este trabajo a) te es más fácil concentrarte en el problema b) puedes buscar soluciones ya existentes c) haces que poner las preguntas aquí sean más cortas y d) al ser más cortas, es más fácil entenderlas y que alguien te conteste.

Comment: @SJuan76 Gracias por tu ayuda pero la solución fue en mi método **cargarDatos()** hice  `String fecha = jdcFechaVencimiento.getDateFormatString();
        Date date = jdcFechaVencimiento.getDate();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(fecha);` y en mi metodo **obtener()** dentro del siglo **while** realice `Date miFechaYHora = new Date(rs.getTimestamp("fechaVencimiento").getTime());
                jdcFechaVencimiento.setDate(miFechaYHora);` agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String formatofecha=String.valueOf(tbcliente.getValueAt(tbcliente.getSelectedRow(),6));
       
       SimpleDateFormat s=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
       java.util.Date fecha;
          try {
              fecha=(java.util.Date)s.parse(formatofecha);
              dtpFecha.setDate(fecha);
        
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(clientes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

recuerda que el 6 es la posición de tu columna